# Jenkins no such method error maven project

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Unable to build my java project which have maven 3.0 same as my jenkins version. jenkins has pulled the code correctly but is not able to complete parsing of pom.xml.

Following are the errors given by jenkins:

```
I[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/main/assembly/package.xml
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:139)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject.getProjectBuildingRequest()Lorg/apache/maven/project/ProjectBuildingRequest;
    at hudson.maven.reporters.MavenFingerprinter.getLocalRepository(MavenFingerprinter.java:162)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.MavenFingerprinter.recordParents(MavenFingerprinter.java:142)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.MavenFingerprinter.postBuild(MavenFingerprinter.java:110)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.recordProjectEnded(Maven3Builder.java:555)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.projectFailed(Maven3Builder.java:542)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:71)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.BuilderCommon.handleBuildError(BuilderCommon.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:314)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:151)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:117)
    ... 21 more
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
channel stopped
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:179)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at ......remote call to Channel to Maven [java, -cp, /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.12-alpha-1.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.0.5/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.2.3.jar, org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main, /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.0.5, /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-3.7.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.12-alpha-1.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.12-alpha-1.jar, 33072](Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1545)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:253)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:830)
    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache$MavenProcess.call(ProcessCache.java:161)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:879)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:490)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:139)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:184)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:181)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject.getProjectBuildingRequest()Lorg/apache/maven/project/ProjectBuildingRequest;
    at hudson.maven.reporters.MavenFingerprinter.getLocalRepository(MavenFingerprinter.java:162)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.MavenFingerprinter.recordParents(MavenFingerprinter.java:142)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.MavenFingerprinter.postBuild(MavenFingerprinter.java:110)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.recordProjectEnded(Maven3Builder.java:555)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.projectFailed(Maven3Builder.java:542)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:71)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.BuilderCommon.handleBuildError(BuilderCommon.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:314)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:151)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:117)
    ... 21 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

My jenkin's version is 2.6 and I am this is the maven project of jenkins  Any help regarding this will be very helpful to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error by updating my jenkins and removing this from my maven:

```
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/package.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
```

because jenkins was unable to find package.xml at that location of my code.

Answer (score 1):

I found many reference to this issue, it looks like that updating the Maven version to Maven 3.0.4 fixes the issue..

Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/-IzGYBryfkM